# How to analyse if transitive Dependency is set "changing"?

Tags: gradle, dependencies

Currently I have an issue in behaviour of my dependencies. It seems not all dependencies are marked "changing" that need to. I tried to verify this using the build.gradle scripts. For the direct dependencies the check is simple.

```
configurations.all {
  incoming.beforeResolve {
    it.dependencies.each { dep ->
      if ( dep.getVersion()?.endsWith( '-SNAPSHOT' ) ) {
        println dep
        println dep.isChanging()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This way I noticed that the SNAPSHOTs for example are not marked "changing". Now I am uncertain how the transitive dependencies behave. But I am not able to get the transitive dependencies by accessing the API before resolving.

Using the gradle parameter '--refresh-dependencies' is no option (but works). But for our external offices the delay using this parameter is very high. Sometimes this will be several minutes per build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was solved a while ago. I think the problem was somewhere in the gradle dependency discriptor management.

What solved the problem in most cases?

```
allprojects {
  configurations.all {
    incoming.beforeResolve {
      it.dependencies.each { dep ->
        if ( dep.getVersion()?.endsWith( '-SNAPSHOT' ) ) {
          if ( dep.metaClass.respondsTo( 'setChanging', Boolean ) ) {
            dep.setChanging( true )
          }
        }
      }
    }

    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
  }
}
```

On the other hand, sometimes the issue is still given. But then there was an issue, that the descriptors in the gradle cache directory where not correctly updated (maybe same calculated hash value for the artifacts).

Less than 1 to 3 times per month deleting the dependency discriptor folder while having ~100 developers seems possible to handle.

Comment: The syntax may have since the answer was written, I had to change dep.metaClass.respondsTo( 'setChanging', Boolean ) to dep.metaClass.respondsTo(dep, 'setChanging', boolean ) for the code to work properly